# Determine SSL/TLS version in WCF Service request

Tags: wcf, ssl

I am trying to find a way to determine the version of SSL/TLS that is being negotiated as clients connect to my WCF service. Preferably I would like to determine this in code so that it can be saved to the database as part of the request being handled along with the other information in the request being saved.

The ultimate purpose is that we have old clients that do not support TLS 1.2 connecting to the server and we need a way of identifying them so we can update them before we disable old cipher suites on the server completely. (A way of identifying them that doesn't involve doing the update and looking at who stops connecting).

How can I capture this information?

Answer (score 0):

In the wcf client, you first add the following code:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

The version of TLS generally depends on the client .net version:

For.Net 4.6 and above it will default to TLS 1.2 and you do not need to specify TLS 1.2.

For.NET 4.0 you need the below instead.

```
 System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

For .NET 3.5 or below you need to install the appropriate Microsoft Patch for your OS.

In addition, you can try the method in [this Case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60377730/c-sharp-wcf-web-service-and-how-to-detect-client-tls-version) to determine the version and refer to the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls) for more detailed information.